# SetState doesn't seem to be updating FutureBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, http-get

I have built an app where I fetch data from the internet using these instructions https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

I then send a http POST request to a web service where the parameters are taken from the users selection, which updates the data on the fly.

I can see that this part of my works as the JSON data updates on the server immediately, and when I restart the application the latest data pulls through. However, I am trying to implement a button that will refresh this data 'live', and it seems to work but **only** when I click the button twice.

My (simplified) code is below:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

//get Current Date
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Hide the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: '',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class Match {
  final List matches;
  final String date;
  final String title;

  Match({
    required this.matches,
    required this.date,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Match.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Match(
      matches: json['matches'],
      date: json['date'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var keyName = "";
  var id = "";
  final Map myMap = {};
  late Future<Match> futureMatch;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureMatch = readJson();
  }

  // Fetch content from the json file
  Future<Match> readJson() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('<myServer/myFile.json>'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Match.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }

  void _showPopup() {
    Future<Match> makePostRequest() async {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(
          '<myServer/myWebService.php?date=' +
              formattedDate +
              '&id=' +
              id +
              '&' +
              keyName.toString() +
              '=' +
              myMap[keyName]));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Match.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load data');
      }
    }

    var list = new List<int>.generate(20, (i) => i + 1);

    // set up the AlertDialog
    MaterialApp gridHolder = MaterialApp(
        home: new Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: new Container(
        width: 500.0,
        height: 500.0,
        child: GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 5, children: [
          for (var i in list)
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                myMap[keyName] = i.toString();
                makePostRequest();
                Navigator.pop(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                );
              },
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(i.toString(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.blue))),
              ),
            ),
        ]),
      ),
    ));

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return gridHolder;
      },
    );
  }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            'Matches',
          ),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
          child: Column(children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  futureMatch = readJson();
                });
              },
              child: Text('Refresh Data'),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            ),
            FutureBuilder<Match>(
              future: futureMatch,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return snapshot.data!.matches.length > 0
                      ? Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: snapshot.data!.matches.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Card(
                                ...
                                );
                              }),
                        )
                      : Container();
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

It is this part in particular that doesn't seem to be working:

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      futureMatch = readJson();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Refresh Data'),
                ),
```

Please can anybody help me work out why I need to press the button twice for the latest data to pull through?

Thanks!

Comment: setState immediately rebuilds but readJson returns a Future, so it needs some time to fetch data. Switch your function to async, then wait for readJson before setState().  You can try this: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {  futureMatch = await readJson();
                    setState(() {
                     
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Refresh Data'),
                ),

Comment: @SuatÖzkaya thank you for your response! I have tried this but get the error 'A value of type 'Match' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<Match>'.' As soon as I remove the 'await' there are no errors again, do you know why this is? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response from @Suat Özkaya who advised that readJson needed some time to fetch the data, I decided to wrap it in a Future.delayed class which seems to have done the trick:

```
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1200), () {                
                  setState(() {
                    futureMatch = readJson();
                  });
                });
              },
```

This will help for now but any other ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

readJson return a future as said by @suat Ozkaya, that's why you need to use async await in the onPress call.
Try this:

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: async() {
                    var response = await readJson();

                    setState(() {
                      futureMatch = response;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Refresh Data'),
                ),
```

Or you can also write an async function that will return a future, you can call that function in onPressed function.